# How to add multiple labels using Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

What's the best way of setting multiple labels in this CYPHER command?

Setting properties works with substitution but i can't work out how to set labels (either with or without substitution.)

```
var cypherQuery = _graphClient.Cypher
    .Merge("(n:Node { Token: {token} })")
    .OnCreate().Set("n = {properties}")
    .OnMatch().Set("n = {properties}")
    .WithParams(new
    {
        token = principalMetaNode.Token,
        properties = parameterMap
});
```

(principalMetaNode.Token is a Guid.)

Answer (score 3):

`CREATE` and `MERGE` allow you to specify multiple labels at the same time.

So, instead of:

```
.Merge("(n:Node { Token: {token} })")
```

you can do something like this (where `Second` and `Third` are also labels):

```
.Merge("(n:Node:Second:Third { Token: {token} })")
```

#### CAVEAT

You should be careful when you specify multiple labels in a `MERGE` clause, as you could accidentally create what you might consider to be duplicate nodes.

For example, suppose you execute a query like this and it creates a node:

```
...
.Merge("(n:Node { Token: 'abc' })")
...
```

And later on you execute a query like this:

```
...
.Merge("(n:Node:Second:Third { Token: 'abc' })")
...
```

The latter query will *also* create a node because there was not yet a node will *all 3 labels*.

*On the other hand, if you executed those queries in the opposite order, no new node would be created.*

Comment: Hi,

A couple of issues:

1) I need to match nodes with the label 'Node' and the specified value for the Token property only - if I add other labels to the MATCH clause, will it only match nodes which also have all of these labels?

2) I need to add an arbitrary number of labels from an array of strings (similar to adding a collection of properties which works OK.) Should I just concatenate the strings with ':'? Seems wrong to do this due to security issues!

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Hi Richard, 1) Yes - if you put multiple labels on - you will only get the Nodes back with all of those labels. 2) Yes, you need to concat, I would do: `.Merge($"(n:{string.Concat(":", labels) {Token: {{token}})` - by security - I assume you mean some sort of injection - potentially - this could happen if it's coming from external sources, but you could mitigate it by parsing the 'Labels' and making sure that's all they are. Or you could use an `Enum` for the Relationships, or allow them only to come from a specific `static class` / list of `const`s.